# FindFailed with error message implying find success in SikuliX?

Tags: java, image-recognition, sikuli

I am writing a desktop grabber with the help of SikuliX (which is a Java wrapper around Sikuli) and it requires to search an image on the screen. Sometimes, I receive a `FindFailed` exception, but the error message looks like:

```
FindFailed: MYIMAGENAME.png: (26x27) seen at (1213, 795) with 0,99 in R[325,29 1040x807]@S(0) E:Y, T:3,0
```

Which obviously implies that image was seen at (1213, 795).

Then why did it throw the "not found" exception?

Maybe I can set the score threshold somehow?

Comment: Have you got any logs?

Comment: You can add setFindFailedResponse(PROMPT) in the beginning of the script to trigger a popup on FindFailed, see: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/262893

Comment: Changing http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html#Settings.MinSimilarity is NOT recommended. Intermittent success suggests a timing problem.